# if any changes(like insert update) happened load the changes from one table to another using task and procedure in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example consider a student table and student_info table two table has identical data if any changes happened in student table like insert delete update this same changes can be capture and load in student_info table using task and procedure please send code

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “same data”? Do you mean the tables are identical, or they have a subset of columns in common, or something else? Is there a good reason for duplicating data between tables?

Comment: If the `student` table is where all of the changes occur, you could use a stream and task to apply any changes to the student table to the `student_info` table.